# What distinguishes the FCP trial from the actual FCP X?

Tags: macos, catalina, final-cut-pro

I recently downloaded Final Cut Pro Trial and then after using it for a while decided to get Final Cut Pro from the App Store. Whenever I open Final Cut, it still shows as the trial. I think that the problem is caused by the source version in `version.plist`. Does this distinguish the trial from the actual version? What could be the other causes of this problem? Thanks!

Also, if it helps, I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.

Answer (score 1):

According to the App Store, the current version is 10.4.8. Your best course of action is to delete the trial app (or indeed all instances of FCP if you're unsure which is which), and then download the purchased version from the Store again.

Comment: I was looking for the version source, not the version of the App. I’ve already tried this but i have the same problem. I contacted Apple Support and they don’t know what to do. Like I said above, FCP owners can find the source version of FCP at /Users/Final\ Cut\ Pro.app/version.plist.   Thanks though!

Comment: What makes you think that's the problem? The version downloaded from the MAS would have the correct version.plist. It's possible that the demo and purchased version are identical: only the MASReceipt distinguishes them. But if not: then delete the Demo.

Comment: I’ve already deleted both and reinstalled. Can you find the version for me and tell me that? I think that’s the issue because the version still shows up as FCP trial even after a reinstall and reboot.

Comment: Even better, if you own FCP, can you send a Screenshot of ```version.plist``` so I can compare it with mine. Thanks!

Comment: Are you signed in to the AppleID that purchased the app? Has the trial expired yet, or not? Are you able to install the Additional Content, which is not available to the trial?

Comment: No, I am not able to install Additional Content. I am signed into the Apple ID that purchased the app. The trial has not expired but has been deleted from the Mac.